# Prove ${n \choose k} = {n \choose k-1}\frac{n-k+1}{k}$

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation

I am looking to prove, by induction, the following equality:$${n \choose k} = {n \choose k-1}\frac{n-k+1}{k}$$ From Pascal's identity, I know we have that $${n+1 \choose k} = {n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1}$$ The problem gives the following hint: get ${n \choose k-1}$ and ${n+1 \choose k-1}$ in terms of ${n \choose k-1}$. I have been rearranging Pascal's identity for hours now, and can't seem to come up with a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with direct calculation?  $\frac {n!}{k!\,(n-k)!}=\frac {n!}{(k-1)!\,(n-k+1)!}\times \frac {n-k+1}k$

Comment: @lulu nothing's wrong in it. But is always useful to learn other methods as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Using your method**, $$\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$
Use $\binom{n+1}{k}=\frac{n+1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}$
$$\frac{n+1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}= \binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$
$$\binom{n}{k}=\left(\frac{n+1}{k}-1\right)\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{n-k+1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}=\frac{(n-k+1)n!}{(n-k+1)!k!}=\frac{n!(n-k+1)}{(n-k+1)!(k-1)!k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k+1)!(k-1)!}\frac{(n-k+1)}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{n-k+1}{k}$$

Comment: You made a mistake in the last step

Comment: Thank you...forgot i was changing the binomial coefficient...