# Prove that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{n-k+1}{k}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I need to prove ${n \choose k} = {n \choose k -1}\frac{n -k +1}{k}$ by induction for $k$ in $\{2,\ldots,n\}$. Can someone show be the proof?
Here is the work I have done for the inductive step:
Assume true for ${n \choose k} = {n \choose k -1}\frac{n -k +1}{k}$
We need to show ${n+1 \choose k} = {n+1 \choose k -1}\frac{n+1 -k +1}{k}$

${n+1 \choose k} = {n+1 \choose k -1}\frac{n+1 -k +1}{k}$

${n \choose k} + {n \choose k-1} = ({n \choose k -1}+{n \choose k -2})\frac{n+2 -k}{k}$

Then by the inductive hypothesis:

${n \choose k -1}\frac{n -k +1}{k} +{n \choose k -2}\frac{n -k +2}{k-1} = ({n \choose k -1}+{n \choose k -2})\frac{n+2 -k}{k}$

I cannot figure out where to go from here

Comment: How much of it can you do? What have you tried?

Comment: No, we are not going to do *all* your work for you; it should be your own work. We will *help out* if you show us what you have tried and where you get stuck, so do please show your efforts.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to induct, though? Depending on what you know about $\binom{n}{k}$, this is trivial/almost trivial from the definition.

Comment: No need for induction. It is trivial from the fact that $ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ and $\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}$. Divide the two of them and you get your desired result.

Comment: $\binom{n}k=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+2)}{(k-1)!}\cdot\frac{n-k+1}k=\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{n-k+1}k$ @PopularPower, but maybe the student is **required**.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1682306/721644).